# How do I test Java Apps in Win7/XP

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, java

I was wondering if someone could help me. I often am asked to test various application in the windows environment. We have a vender who has built a Java app and from time-to-time the application acts very strange. The logs from the app will not post anything strange and windows will see nothing strange either with the Java process. Can someone help me by pointing to a tool or something that help isolate java vm specific issues like heap etc.. All the tools out there seem to be developers tools that require either the source code or a very indepth knowledge of the code of the application. If I can't point to something specific with the application it becomes hard to go back to the vender and have them fix something I can't define. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: focus on the question in what way is it acting very strange. without source there is little you will establish. Just try to find ways to reproduce the strangeness.

Comment: Thats the problem we are experiencing random lockups and the vender will only work on reproducable issues. so we are kind of stuck. There has to be some insight somewhere on the JVM to see more from that level.

Answer (score 0):

As you already stated, there's little, if anything, that you can know about the inner workings of an app without having access to the *source code*. Here are a couple of things you can actually know:

- Error reports. Via *logs* or the *console*. You can run the app from a console (`java "yourapp.exe"`) and hope that the developer echoes something to the `stdout` or even `stderr`.
- Exceptions. Again, if your run your app from the *console*, chances are that there's an uncaught `exception` that you can look more into. Again, hope that the developer echoes something about it.

You can refer to this question about the JVM logging and it's default locations on a Windows system: [What is default jvm error log location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102293/what-is-default-jvm-error-log-location)